Multiple Records Identifying Problem Rows
My table from PeopleSoft PS_JOB has ID Numbers (my example, only one emplid 12345).
The IDs can have multiple employee records (the example has 3 empl_rcd total: 0, 1, 2). This means the employee has three jobs within the organization.
Each EMPL_RCD has various action-action_reason combinations that represent HR changes (things like rehire, term, pay rate increase, etc).
The HR changes are effective dated. The HR changes are represented in rows with an EFFDT (start date) and an END_DATE (end date) of that HR change.
Empl_rcd 0 has 10 rows worth of HR changes.
Empl_rcd 1 has 6 rows worth of HR changes.
Empl_Rcd 2 has 2 rows worth of HR changes.
The empl_Rcds can be active or terminated.
I have the data sorted by EFFDT so we can see the order of HR changes.
Initially, empl_Rcd 0 was the only record that existed.
Empl_rcd 0 was hired (HIR-INH) EFFDT 6/14/21.
Then, 0 had a pay rate change (PAY-SPI) EFFDT 3/1/22.
Then, 0 was terminated (TER-FXD) EFFDT 9/1/22.
Then, 0 was rehired (REH-REH) EFFDT 11/1/22. This is important. This row has the correct ACTION_REASON value of "REH". Since at this point in time, there are no other active empl_rcds, the correction action_Reason to use is "REH." Together with the action, the values are REH-REH.
Then, 0 has a pay rate change (PAY-CWP) EFFDT 2/1/23.
Then, a new empl_rcd is added--empl_Rcd = 1. This is important. Empl_rcd 1 is rehired (REH) with action_reason "ADL" EFFDT  3/1/22. The action action_Reason combo of REH-ADL is correct because at this point in time, empl_rcd = 0 was active. Anytime there is an active job and someone is rehiring another job, the action_Reason to use must be 'ADL' (not REH).
Empl_Rcd 1 has a PAY-CWP EFFDT 5/1/23.
Empl_Rcd 1 is terminated (TER-CTG) EFFDT 7/1/23.
Then, this is important, empl_rcd = 1 gets rehired incorrectly.
Empl_rcd = 1 has action REH with action_Reason "REH" EFFDT 10/1/23. This is wrong.
Because empl_rcd = 0 was active at this point in time, this row should have been REH-ADL (not REH-REH).
These are the problem rows I'm trying to identify.
I need help identifying certain REH rows that need the action_Reason fixed.
Rows 11 and 16 are both wrong and should be ADL since there was always at least one active record before the rehire. These are the two rows I'd like to select in a SQL.
I can't figure out how to isolate the problem rows. I was attempting using the EFFDT and END_DATE but I'm not anywhere near figuring this out.
Maybe lag or lead would help?
Identifying rows within multiple date ranges is something I've never been able to select...



EMPLID
EMPL_RCD
EFFDT
END_DATE
EFFSEQ
ACTION
ACTION_REASON
EMPL_STATUS




12345
0
6/14/21
3/1/22
0
HIR
INH
A


12345
0
3/01/22
9/1/22
0
PAY
SPI
A


12345
0
9/01/22
11/1/22
0
TER
CTG
T


12345
0
11/1/22
2/1/23
0
REH
REH
A


12345
0
2/1/23
4/1/23
0
PAY
CWP
A


12345
1
3/1/23
5/1/23
0
REH
ADL
A


12345
0
4/1/23
8/16/23
0
TER
CTG
T


12345
1
5/1/23
7/1/23
0
PAY
CWP
A


12345
1
7/1/23
10/1/23
0
TER
CTG
T


12345
0
8/16/23
12/1/23
0
REH
REH
A


12345
1
10/1/23
10/16/23
0
REH
REH
A


12345
1
10/16/23
12/16/23
0
PAY
CWP
A


12345
0
12/1/23
3/1/24
0
TER
CTG
T


12345
2
12/1/23
4/16/24
0
REH
ADL
A


12345
1
12/16/23
1/1/50
0
TER
CTG
T


12345
0
3/1/24
6/16/24
0
REH
REH
A**


12345
2
4/16/24
1/1/50
0
TER
CTG
T


12345
0
6/14/21
1/1/50
0
TER
CTG
T



All the selects I've been trying haven't worked :( They're not even worth sharing.
Update: user d s gave me a great SQL. I ran it in my database, and two of the rows have the wrong error message:
output from the SQL d s gave

EDIT after clarifications
Presumably you use Oracle . You'll be looking at the most recent action of each employee record to see if any weren't termination. I'm also presuming that 'TER' will be the final entry in such cases. You might need to limit the set of actions if that's not reliably true.
The inner query computes a list of the IsTerminated statuses (Y/N) for each record up each date. The outer grouping min(IsTerminated) determines whether any of them are 'N' aka "Active" (falling earlier in the alphabet.) You can remove the translation from T/A -> Y/N if preferred.
select
    EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, EFFDT,
    min(ACTION) as ACTION, min(ACTION_REASON) as ACTION_REASON,
    min(IsTerminated) as IsRehire,
    case when min(ACTION_REASON) = 'REH' and min(IsTerminated) = 'N' or
              min(ACTION_REASON) = 'ADL' and min(IsTerminated) = 'Y' then '!!' else '' end as IsError
from PS_Job j cross apply (
    select
        case first_value(ACTION) over (partition by EMPLID, EMPL_RCD order by EFFDT desc)
            when 'TER' then 'Y' else 'N' end as IsTerminated
    from PS_Job j2
    where j2.EMPLID = j.EMPLID and j2.EFFDT < j.EFFDT
) terminations
where ACTION = 'REH'
group by EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, EFFDT
order by EMPLID, EFFDT;

https://dbfiddle.uk/nuuobi3V
There might be a slightly cleaner way so I'll think about it some more. You should also specify desired output if this doesn't work for you.
Cleaner version?
This second variation pushes the aggregation down into the subquery so that the top level is cleaner. Otherwise it works basically the same way. Another difference is using an outer apply so that all rows are returning while pushing down the filter on 'REH' so that only those rows get the lookup applied.
select
    EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, EFFDT, ACTION, ACTION_REASON,
    IsRehire,
    case when ACTION_REASON = 'REH' and IsRehire = 'N' or
              ACTION_REASON = 'ADL' and IsRehire = 'Y' then '!!' else '' end as IsError
from PS_Job j outer apply (
    select min(IsTerminated) as IsRehire from (
        select
            case first_value(ACTION) over (partition by EMPLID, EMPL_RCD order by EFFDT desc)
                when 'TER' then 'Y' else 'N' end as IsTerminated
        from PS_Job j2
        where j2.EMPLID = j.EMPLID and j2.EFFDT < j.EFFDT and j.ACTION = 'REH'
    ) t0
) t 
order by EMPLID, EFFDT;

https://sqlfiddle.com/oracle/online-compiler?id=d5d2ce4b-b586-46d1-83be-b8853d823460
Original attempt
I don't think your requirement is fully clear--for one I cannot make sense of the "all-records-that-exist-have-status-T stipulation. But I think this will help get you started as it will bundle each set of rows between 'REH' actions. Using the counts I think you can derive the rest of what you need:
with grp as (
    select *,
        count(case when action = 'REH' then 1 end)
             over (partition by emplid order by effdt desc) as grp
    from PS_Job
)
select emplid, min(effdt) as start_date, max(end_date) as end_date)
    count(case when empl_status = 'A' then 1 end) as A,
    count(case when empl_status = 'T' then 1 end) as T
where grp > 0
group by emplid, grp
order by emplid, grp desc;

Another idea is that you may need to both partition and group with the empl_rcd column. You haven't fully explained what that's for either.

I edited my first post to help explain the requirements. Please let me know if that makes more sense!

@Descagnia Well take a look at the update. I had started to suspect this was the way you wanted to interpret it but it's frustrating to be wrong and spend the time working with invalid assumptions.

@Descagnia This works in Oracle as well: https://sqlfiddle.com/oracle/online-compiler?id=2a6f2136-4778-4fa3-b1d4-29bd8b8b3f8d

Your new SQL worked in my database! I'm still trying to comprehend how you did it lol I've never used CROSS APPLY before nor first_value nor have a used min for a non-date field. I'm going to keep reviewing until I figure out how this entire SQL works!

for your SQL under EDIT after clarifications post, I'm kind of lost. I can't figure out how the cross apply inner query works (IsTerminated area). So it's partitioned by emplid and empl_Rcd and then sorted by EFFDT desc. but what does the first_value (ACTION) select? and I see the EFFDT selected must be j2.effdt < j.effdt...but this only looks at EFFDTs within the same empl_Rcd (not across empl_Rcds)? I'm just really lost on how this section ends up applying either Y or N or each row...

@Descagnia For every event it looks up every prior event. For each of those rows it then looks across all the other rows with the same empl_rcd to grab the most recent action. (That step uses first_value() with a descending sort rather than last_value() because of some weirdness with the default window framing.) This results in multiple copies of the same data as it's applied row by row so distinct can be useful to make sense of it. If all the values are 'TER" the the minimum of the case expression and aggregation will be 'Y'. If any evaluates to 'N' though, the minimum is 'N' too.

I'm still stuck. I'm sorry! Can you help explain it with a row? For this row: empl_rcd 0, EFFDT 3/1/24, Action REH, Action_Reason REH, empl_Status A then we're selecting every prior event which would be rows 12/16/23 through 6/14/21 (which would be 10 rows)? but for each of those 10 rows, I am so confused what we pull from there....I'm sorry I don't understand :( if you wouldn't mind using row empl_rcd 0, EFFDT 3/1/24, Action REH, Action_Reason REH, empl_Status A as an example and what the outputs are for that, I'd really appreciate it!

@Descagnia This just display the intermediate results from the inner query for that particular row. Each of the Y/N values will be the same within each empl_rcd. Ultimately these still need to be collapsed into a single value that determinates the "termination status". https://sqlfiddle.com/oracle/online-compiler?id=dd5f701c-57a3-4a5e-8859-c8827e79cac8

Thank you! I think I'm getting it! Now though, I have another issue. We have many empl_Rcd in my system, but I need to ignore empl_Rcds 70 and above. I tried adding  "and j2.empl_Rcd < 70" into the cross apply inner query  (IsTerminated) to only look at empl_Rcds below 70 but that didn't work. This query still looks at empl_Rcds >=70 when determining whether an empl_Rcd was Y or N. Is there a way to fix this?

It sounds like you need to filter on both j2.EMPL_RCD  and j.EMPL_RCD. j2 is what's driving the look back parameters. I don't have a clear picture of the full output you need on the j side. A CTE is also one way to consolidate that kind of logic.

This was a bit tricky to understand and if I got it wright you could try this:
--      S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table PS_JOB As
  ( Select  12345 "EMPLID", 0 "EMPL_RCD", To_Date('6/14/21', 'mm/dd/yy') "EFFDT", To_Date('3/1/22', 'mm/dd/yy') "END_DATE", 0 "EFFSEQ", 'HIR' "ACTION", 'INH' "ACTION_REASON", 'A' "EMPL_STATUS" From Dual Union All 
    Select  12345,  0,  To_Date('3/01/22',  'mm/dd/yy'), To_Date('9/1/22',   'mm/dd/yy'),  0,   'PAY',  'SPI',  'A' From Dual Union All 
    Select  12345,  0,  To_Date('9/01/22',  'mm/dd/yy'), To_Date('11/1/22',   'mm/dd/yy'), 0,   'TER',  'CTG',  'T' From Dual Union All 
    Select  12345,  0,  To_Date('11/1/22',  'mm/dd/yy'), To_Date('2/1/23',    'mm/dd/yy'), 0,   'REH',  'REH',  'A' From Dual Union All 
    Select  12345,  0,  To_Date('2/1/23',   'mm/dd/yy'), To_Date('4/1/23',    'mm/dd/yy'), 0,   'PAY',  'CWP',  'A' From Dual Union All 
    Select  12345,  1,  To_Date('3/1/23',   'mm/dd/yy'), To_Date('5/1/23',    'mm/dd/yy'), 0,   'REH',  'ADL',  'A' From Dual Union All 
    Select  12345,  0,  To_Date('4/1/23',   'mm/dd/yy'), To_Date('8/16/23',   'mm/dd/yy'), 0,   'TER',  'CTG',  'T' From Dual Union All 
    Select  12345,  1,  To_Date('5/1/23',   'mm/dd/yy'), To_Date('7/1/23',    'mm/dd/yy'), 0,   'PAY',  'CWP',  'A' From Dual Union All 
    Select  12345,  1,  To_Date('7/1/23',   'mm/dd/yy'), To_Date('10/1/23',   'mm/dd/yy'), 0,   'TER',  'CTG',  'T' From Dual Union All 
    Select  12345,  0,  To_Date('8/16/23',  'mm/dd/yy'), To_Date('12/1/23',   'mm/dd/yy'), 0,   'REH',  'REH',  'A' From Dual Union All 
    Select  12345,  1,  To_Date('10/1/23',  'mm/dd/yy'), To_Date('10/16/23',  'mm/dd/yy'), 0,   'REH',  'REH',  'A' From Dual Union All 
    Select  12345,  1,  To_Date('10/16/23', 'mm/dd/yy'), To_Date('12/16/23',  'mm/dd/yy'), 0,   'PAY',  'CWP',  'A' From Dual Union All 
    Select  12345,  0,  To_Date('12/1/23',  'mm/dd/yy'), To_Date('3/1/24',    'mm/dd/yy'), 0,   'TER',  'CTG',  'T' From Dual Union All 
    Select  12345,  2,  To_Date('12/1/23',  'mm/dd/yy'), To_Date('4/16/24',   'mm/dd/yy'), 0,   'REH',  'ADL',  'A' From Dual Union All 
    Select  12345,  1,  To_Date('12/16/23', 'mm/dd/yy'), To_Date('1/1/50',    'mm/dd/yy'), 0,   'TER',  'CTG',  'T' From Dual Union All 
    Select  12345,  0,  To_Date('3/1/24',   'mm/dd/yy'), To_Date('6/16/24',   'mm/dd/yy'), 0,   'REH',  'REH',  'A**' From Dual Union All 
    Select  12345,  2,  To_Date('4/16/24',  'mm/dd/yy'), To_Date('1/1/50',    'mm/dd/yy'), 0,   'TER',  'CTG',  'T' From Dual Union All 
    Select  12345,  0,  To_Date('6/14/21',  'mm/dd/yy'), To_Date('1/1/50',    'mm/dd/yy'), 0,   'TER',  'CTG',  'T' From Dual 
  );

... first create a cte that will prepare your data for Case expression conditions in the main sql. You need to get in the same row EFFDT and END_DATE of the termination. I used Max() Over() analytic function with propper Partition By, Order By and windowing part.
--    P r e p a r i n g    T h e   D a t a :
WITH 
  grid AS
    ( Select     ROWNUM "RN", EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, EFFDT, END_DATE, EFFSEQ, ACTION, ACTION_REASON, EMPL_STATUS, 
                 CASE WHEN ACTION != 'TER' 
                      THEN Max(Case When EMPL_STATUS = 'T' Then EFFDT End) 
                           Over( Partition By EMPLID, EMPL_RCD Order By EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, EFFDT, END_DATE  
                                 Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding ) 
                 ELSE EFFDT
                 END "EFFDT_TERMINATED", 
                 CASE WHEN ACTION != 'TER' 
                      THEN Max(Case When EMPL_STATUS = 'T' Then END_DATE End) 
                           Over( Partition By EMPLID, EMPL_RCD Order By EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, EFFDT, END_DATE  
                                 Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding ) 
                 ELSE END_DATE
                 END "END_DATE_TERMINATED" 
     From       PS_JOB 
    )

... use Case expression conditions to check if the ACTION_REASON column is ok or not for ACTION = 'REH'. Keep in mind that Case works sequentialy (first When condition true returns the Then value and exits Case)...
--    M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT   EMPLID, EMPL_RCD, EFFDT, END_DATE, EFFSEQ, ACTION, ACTION_REASON, EMPL_STATUS, 
         Case When (STAT = 'A' And ACTION = 'REH' And ACTION_REASON != 'ADL')
                  OR 
                   (STAT = 'T' And ACTION = 'REH' And ACTION_REASON != 'ADL' And
                      Case When Max(Case When STAT = 'A' Then END_DATE End) 
                                 Over(Partition By EMPLID) Between EFFDT And END_DATE
                           Then 1
                      End = 1
                   )
              Then 'ERR - ACTION_REASON should be ADL - there are active EMPLIDs'
              --
              When STAT = 'T' And ACTION = 'REH' And ACTION_REASON != 'REH'
              Then 'ERR - ACTION_REASON should be REH - there are no active EMPLIDs'
              When STAT = 'T' And ACTION = 'REH' And ACTION_REASON = 'REH'
              Then 'OK'
              --
              When 
              Case When Max(Case When STAT = 'A' Then END_DATE End) 
                           Over(Partition By EMPLID) Between EFFDT And END_DATE 
                  Then 1 
             Else 0 
             End = 1 And ACTION = 'REH' And ACTION_REASON != 'ADL'
              THEN 'ERR - ACTION_REASON should be ADL - there are active EMPLIDs'
              --
              When STAT = 'A' And ACTION = 'REH' And ACTION_REASON = 'ADL'
              Then 'OK'
         Else '-'
         End "NOTICE"
FROM ( SELECT   g.*, 
               Case When g.EMPL_STATUS = 'T' Then 'TERM'
                    When EFFDT Between EFFDT_TERMINATED And END_DATE_TERMINATED And
                         END_DATE Between EFFDT_TERMINATED And END_DATE_TERMINATED
                    Then 'T'
               Else 'A'
               End  "STAT"
      FROM     grid g
   )
ORDER BY  RN

/*      R e s u l t : 
EMPLID  EMPL_RCD    EFFDT       END_DATE    EFFSEQ  ACTION  ACTION_REASON   EMPL_STATUS   NOTICE
------  ----------  ----------  ---------- -------  ------  -------------   ------------  ---------------------------------------------------------------
12345            0  14-JUN-21   01-MAR-22       0   HIR     INH             A             -
12345            0  01-MAR-22   01-SEP-22       0   PAY     SPI             A             -
12345            0  01-SEP-22   01-NOV-22       0   TER     CTG             T             -
12345            0  01-NOV-22   01-FEB-23       0   REH     REH             A             OK
12345            0  01-FEB-23   01-APR-23       0   PAY     CWP             A             -
12345            1  01-MAR-23   01-MAY-23       0   REH     ADL             A             OK
12345            0  01-APR-23   16-AUG-23       0   TER     CTG             T             -
12345            1  01-MAY-23   01-JUL-23       0   PAY     CWP             A             -
12345            1  01-JUL-23   01-OCT-23       0   TER     CTG             T             -
12345            0  16-AUG-23   01-DEC-23       0   REH     REH             A             OK
12345            1  01-OCT-23   16-OCT-23       0   REH     REH             A             ERR - ACTION_REASON should be ADL - there are active EMPLIDs
12345            1  16-OCT-23   16-DEC-23       0   PAY     CWP             A             -
12345            0  01-DEC-23   01-MAR-24       0   TER     CTG             T             -
12345            2  01-DEC-23   16-APR-24       0   REH     ADL             A             OK
12345            1  16-DEC-23   01-JAN-50       0   TER     CTG             T             -
12345            0  01-MAR-24   16-JUN-24       0   REH     REH             A**           ERR - ACTION_REASON should be ADL - there are active EMPLIDs
12345            2  16-APR-24   01-JAN-50       0   TER     CTG             T             -
12345            0  14-JUN-21   01-JAN-50       0   TER     CTG             T             -                                                                */


I edited my first post to help explain the requirements. Please let me know if that makes more sense!

I think this may have worked! I'm trying to understand it all. What does "Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding" accomplish?

Update. I checked. There are six possible rows with "notice." Four are selected and labeled correctly. Two rows are pulled incorrectly: empl_rcd 0 effdt 11/1/22 REH REH has error "ERR - ACTION_REASON should be ADL - there are active EMPLIDs" but this should just be OK. Empl_rcd 0 effdt 8/16/23 REH REH has error "ERR - ACTION_REASON should be ADL - there are active EMPLIDs" but this should just be OK. I'm going to see if I can tweak it and fix it. The other rows come up correctly though.

@Descagnia Quote from your question: "Rows 11 and 16 are both wrong and should be ADL since there was always at least one active record before the rehire" end quote. Now in your comment you say those two are ok, but you don't explain  why. Which one is what you need - bad as stated in the question OR ok as in the comment???

I'm sorry for the confusion. Your result looks correct, but when I run the SQLs in my database, two of the rows are different than your result. I'm going to try to add a screenshot of my database output (which I have sorted by EFFDT), and you will see how two of the rows have Notices that are not correct.

Screenshot added to the initial post towards the bottom.

@Descagnia Those two rows are not terminated by the logic used in my code. Could you tell how you consider them terminated and which TER row did that? It's hard for me to tell.
